# K-Fold cross validation using Keras flow from directory

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, neural-network, cross-validation

My current folder structure is:

```
train 
    class1/
         img1.jpg
         img2.jpg
         ...
    class2/
         img3.jpg
         img4.jpg
         ...
test
    class1/
         img1.jpg
         img2.jpg
         ...
    class2/
         img3.jpg
         img4.jpg
         ...
```

My current workflow is:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1.0 / 255, shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True, rotation_range=0.2
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            os.getcwd() + config.DATA + "train",
            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
            class_mode="binary",
            batch_size=batch_size,
)

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
            os.getcwd() + config.DATA + "val",
            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
            class_mode="binary",
            batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

What is the preferred way to make a workflow that includes flow_from_directory call and K-Fold cross-validation (preferably with help of scikit?)

I was thinking about approach to make only one folder with all the data and class labels:

```
  class1
       image1
  class2 
       image2
```

and then shuffle it and split it to K folders (with names liek fold1, fold2, fold3, fold4, fold5).

Then I would just use for cycle like this:

```
for i in range(k):
    validation_generator = flow_from_directory('....data/fold(i)') 
    test_generator = flow_from_directory('...data/fold every other folder)
    ... train model, fit model
```

then just average the val_acc for each model in the cycle model.

Is it a good approach? Is there anything more efficient?

Comment: Or you could put all the data together + have a variable to encode the class and then apply scikit-learn splitting as you said. Your approach sounds fine

Comment: Agreed with @serafeim, this all sounds correct

Comment: Considering that flow_from_directory gets randomly its samples, yes you could do it. But sometimes I do prefer not to change the samples among the K-folds created in the training process, i.e. keeping the same samples for each fold in that execution.